# oracle forms. child form doesn't see main form posted changes

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a trouble with oracle forms. The scenario is:

1. There is main form with a data block that contains records from TABLE_A.
2. User selects a record in data block then press button "Generate details", at that moment records in TABLE_B are generated for the master record in TABLE_A.
3. User press button "Details", the next code is executed:

```
    DECLARE
      L_Item item_master.item%TYPE;
      L_pl_id PARAMLIST;
    BEGIN
      Post;
      P_Destroy_Parameter_List('RTVDTL');
      L_pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('RTVDTL');
      L_Item := :B_RTV_DETAIL.Item;
      Add_Parameter(L_pl_id, 'PM_RTV_ORDER_NO', Text_Parameter, To_Char(:B_RTV_HEAD.Rtv_Order_no));
      Add_Parameter(L_pl_id, 'PM_ITEM', Text_Parameter, To_Char(L_Item));
      --Open_Form('xxlmrtvdetail', ACTIVATE, No_Session, L_pl_id);  
      Call_Form('xxlmrtvdetail', No_Hide, No_Replace, No_Query_Only, No_Share_Library_Data);
    END;
```

4. Detail form is opened, but there are no any records in data block that is linked to the detail table.

If I comment row with "Call_Form" function and uncomment "Open_Form" the data is shown. Also, if I change "Post" with "Commit", the data is shown. It seems that child form is using the other session. Does some one know what could be the reason of the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Forms help says the following for `OPEN_FORM`'s **session_mode**:

> `NO_SESSION` (The default.) Specifies that the opened form should share the same database session as the current form. `POST` and `COMMIT` operations in any form will cause posting, validation, and commit processing to occur for all forms running in the same session.

There's no such thing in `CALL_FORM` so it is quite obvious - use `OPEN_FORM` with `NO_SESSION`. Then you can use `POST` or `COMMIT`, whichever suits your needs.

Comment: Hello, Littlefoot! Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's obvious, but there is one problem with OPEN_FORM. It allows to work with main form when child is open this is unacceptable in my case.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, there's no such thing as a free lunch. If you COMMIT (instead of POST), it'll work - and vice versa. It seems that you'll have to decide which one of those options is acceptable.